# Hide scroll bar before the overflow of the y-axis

Tags: html, css

I have a div that generates a scroll bar on overflow of y-axis, but the problem is that the thingy that contains the scroll bar appears before overflow of the y-axis. How do I hide the thingy that contains the scroll bar before y-axis is overflowed?

**Result:**

```css
div {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div> Hello </div>
```

**Need Result:**

```css
div {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div> Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow-y: auto`. Then the thingy(scrollbar) appears only when there is an overflow